# Terminal window won't remain open

Tags: 22.04, gnome-terminal

Briefly, I can't keep a terminal window open for more than a few seconds. That includes gnome, xterm, uxterm and others I've managed to install through Synaptic Package Manager. I have, through Synaptic, completely removed gnome-terminal and gnome-terminal-data and reinstalled both but the window still closes almost immediately after opening. I have tried many suggestions found online, including looking at the profile with dconf and checking and unchecking things as suggested and nothing has worked.

This problem appeared as nearly as I can tell completely out of the blue. I haven't installed any new software of late other than updates routinely provided.

Any ideas besides a complete reinstall of Ubuntu 22.04LTS at this point?

Comment: If all the terminal emulators are configured to use the same shell, then it is likely the shell that is exiting prematurely - in the case of `bash` for example that's usually because of a misconfiguration in the `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: control alt f1, login if possible and check ~/.bashrc otherwise/or do it from a live session or grub rescue

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Can I just delete that bashrc file? Will it "respawn"? What "misconfiguration" should I look for? Is there a backup someplace?

Comment: You can get a "clean" copy of the default `.bashrc` from the `/etc/skel` directory - rename your current one as a backup just in case it contains other modifications that you may wish to recover

Comment: Thanks much, steeldriver. That worked perfectly!